Insert values in a dataframe depending on the date
I want to put the results of many pivot tables in a dataframe where the dates in the pivot table are the same as the dates in the another dataframe.
I do not wish to simply replace all nan values. The nan values will be important later.
The code below does what I want to do, but I read, for-loops are not recommended in Pandas.
How can I change this to get the same result, but just using Pandas functions, without the for loops?
import pandas as pd

cols = ['date', 'Heavy', 'Light']
daysdf = pd.DataFrame(columns = cols)
# set a dates range
start = '2015-06-06'
end = '2015-07-06'
# daysdf has just all possible dates in the range to start with
# columns Heavy and Light just contain NaN
daysdf['date']= pd.date_range(start=start, end=end)
# fake pivot table
pf = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2015-06-06', '2015-06-16', '2015-06-26', '2015-07-05'],
                   'Heavy': [450, 567, 612, 701],
                   'Light': [450, 567, 612, 701]})

# get index of row in daysdf where pf['date'] = daysdf['date']
indexes = []
for p in pf['date']:
    my_index = daysdf.index[daysdf['date']==p]
    indexes.append(my_index)

# this does what I want to do
count = 0
for i in indexes:
    daysdf.iloc[i, 1] = pf.iloc[count, 1]
    daysdf.iloc[i, 2] = pf.iloc[count, 2]
    count +=1


pf['date']= pd.to_datetime(pf['date']) out = (daysdf.set_index('date').combine_first(pf.set_index('date')).reset_index())

Sorry, but out is just a copy of my pf. Nothing gets inserted in daysdf .Any other suggestions please? I just think, I can achieve what I want without the for loops, but so far, nothing I have tried works!

hmmm, I try your solution and working well. Can you show your output with sample data?

Or maybe need pf['date']= pd.to_datetime(pf['date'])
out = pf.set_index('date').reindex(pd.date_range(start=start, end=end)).reset_index() ?

Can't show you, I'm sorry, but the team here closed the question. You can run the above, it works without any other input from outside, then you will see the results.

I want to get the data from pf['Heavy'] and pf['Light'] in daysdf['Heavy'] and daysdf['Light'] wherever the dates are the same.

OK, then use merge like pf['date']= pd.to_datetime(pf['date']) out = daysdf[['date']].merge(pf, on='date', how='left')

Thanks for trying! Sorry, but that returns an empty dataframe! I see this is not easy!

Do you convert both columns to datetimes? pf['date']= pd.to_datetime(pf['date']) and daysdf['date'] = pd.to_datetime(daysdf['date']) before merge?

Yes, I did that, and to be sure, I did that again, but I get an empty dataframe. Thanks anyway!

Do you try data from question and not working? Or not working real data?

Thanks for your reply! I used your suggestion on my pf and daysdf from the question above, but I am afraid I got first a copy of pf, then an empty result. I can use my code and get what I want, I just thought there should be a better way to achieve this result. I see that is not an easy job! No wonder I am struggling, as a non-Pandas user!

Super, so now working well?

My code above, in the question, works fine. I just thought, maybe there is a better way to achieve the same result. But so far, I have not found anyone who knows a better way to achieve the result I want.
